# Internet explorer focus before addEventListener triggers focus?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, focus

Today I stumbled upon a weird Internet Explorer quirk. I call the focus function of the element and AFTER that I bind the event listener. In all browsers it executes chronological, in IE however it does not.

I have this piece of code:

```js
var t = document.getElementById('focusable');
t.focus();
t.addEventListener('focus', function() {
  alert('This should only happen after the second focus.');
});
```

```html
<input id="focusable">
```

My question is:
**Why does this happen?** and how can I solve it without a `setTimeout(fn,0);` hack.

*Note: I'm using IE11*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Presumably because IE doesn't actually give the element focus until the JavaScript thread has yielded back to the browser.

> and how can I solve it without a setTimeout(fn,0); hack.

<s>Using `setTimeout` seems like the right thing in this situation, not a hack.</s> But not if it doesn't work. :-)

I hate to say it, but it sounds like you probably need a flag and to intentionally ensure the first focus fires your handler:

```js
(function() {
  var flag = false;
  var t = document.getElementById('focusable');
  t.blur();
  t.addEventListener('focus', function() {
    if (!flag) {
      flag = true;
    } else {
      console.log('This should only happen after the second focus.');
    }
  }, false);
  t.focus();
})();
```

```html
<input id="focusable">
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I just tested the consistency of the setTimeout "solution" but it fails occasionally. I put the addEventListener inside the settimeout.

Comment: Thanks T.J. I hate it too but at least this is consistent ;)

Comment: @A1rPun: No worries. Fair warning: The above worked for me in IE11 and Chrome, but Firefox refused to give the field focus. It executes the `t.focus();` line, but doesn't give the field focus -- not even if I put just that bit in a `setTimeout`. V. weird, I know I've set focus in fields with Firefox before...